# scikit-learn svm module and predict function not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, k-means

I am trying to get an SVM to work using scikit-learn but cannot get the results I am expecting. I would like to use k-means to classify roughly 2-5 data clusters and then use an SVM to build a model for that data, for which I can use newer data to predict/classify on the fly. This did not work for me, so I tried manually giving the labels, 500 samples with 3 classified data clusters, to the SVM. I always get the same predicted value of '1' no matter what random data I try to have the SVM predict. What in tarnation is going on....

```
# Attempting 3 clusters: 500 training samples in asarray (x-y coordinate data)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel = 'rbf', C=1, gamma = 1)
clf.fit(asarray,labels)
realData = [[-0.005, -0.01], [-0.005, -0.024], [-0.0075, -0.01], [-0.007, -0.008]]
print(clf.predict(realData))

# output: [1 1 1 1]
```

Please keep in mind this... I only have a couple weeks-worth of experience with python and still only have a general knowledge basis for many machine learning topics.

EDIT: Sample data sets for asarray & labels

asarray:

```
 [[-0.001, -0.008]
 [-0.0055, -0.0236]
 [-0.007, -0.0221]
 ... 
 [-0.008, -0.01]
 [-0.0062, -0.015]
 [-0.0025, -0.009]]
```

labels:

```
[0 2 2 ... 1 1 0]
```

I did not want to list all 500 data elements, so I wrote out a very similar sample instead.

Comment: could you please show us `asarray` and `labels` as well?

Comment: Where did `asarray` come from? The 6 samples of `asarray` you added to the question are not enough to tell if the groups are separable at all, do you know if they are? Could you show a plot of the data in each group and the test data?

Comment: It looks like the points on your feature set are not distinguishable and SVM assigns label 1 to each. Have you experimented with different classifiers? Also, is there a reason why you changed the default gamma parameter to 1?

Comment: SVM is scale sensitive, especially when you don't optimize the kernel parameters through cross validation. Try scaling the data to zero mean and unit variance using `StandardScaler`, check the results with default C and sigma parameters. Another issue might be class imbalance - how many training points do you have for each class? Alternatively you should also try RandomForestClassifier, it is as powerful as SVM but doesn't require as much parameter optimization.

Comment: Not sure if you ever fixed this, but I have had a similar problem for weeks and just got actual good prediction performance from my SVM by changing the gamma value. You could also try the C value as well if needed. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125353/output-of-scikit-svm-in-multiclass-classification-always-gives-same-label